# General server configuration WSO2 EMM

Tags: mysql, wso2

I'm almost through and I got stuck at the [**General Server Configuration**](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM100/General+Server+Configurations) from step 6. As in when I try the 7th step, I receive below error;

> mysql> mysql -u admin -p -D EMM_DB <
>   /usr/local/bin/wso2emm/dbscripts/emm_mysql.sql; ERROR 1064 (42000):
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'mysql -u admin -p -D EMM_DB <
>   /usr/local/bin/wso2emm/dbscripts/emm_mysql.sql' at line 1

I assume that the command I'm issuing is incorrect and if someone could clear out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database name field, should be joined with the -D and also I would suggest to use UTF8 parameter

```
mysql> mysql -u admin -p -DEMM_DB --default_character_set=utf8 < /usr/local/bin/wso2emm/dbscripts/emm_mysql.sql;
```

Comment: I figured out that there were no such DB named `emm_mysql.sql` instead it was `mysql.sql`.